# What does the 'locked' checkbox do in report filters in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning, custom-reports

What does the 'locked' checkbox do in report filters in Salesforce? 
What will be the difference in a report if I check or uncheck this option?

Regards,
ParoTech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you lock the report filter, then after running the report, you cannot change the filter, based on which new report data can be fetched/displayed.

For more information, refer [Filter Report Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_filtering.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link explained it well.